# Programmatically determining the child resources of an Azure resource

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-sdk-.net, azure-sdk

Given an Azure resource, e.g. a storage account:

```
/subscriptions/.../resourceGroups/myresources/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/mystorageaccount
```

Is there any way to programmatically determine that there are child resources under it, e.g. the storage account resource would return:

```
/subscriptions/.../Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/mystorageaccount/blobServices/default
/subscriptions/.../Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/mystorageaccount/fileServices/default
/subscriptions/.../Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/mystorageaccount/queueServices/default
/subscriptions/.../Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/mystorageaccount/tableServices/default
```

I'm particularly interested in child resources that have metrics associated to them. I've dug around a bit in the preview versions of the `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor` and `Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager` packages, but can't spot anything obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resources/listbyresourcegroup) to list down the resources in a resource group

GET `https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/resources?api-version=2019-08-01`

There is no specific API available to list the child resources under specific service as of now. However, there are specific API for each service avaialble for ex. [`AppService`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/)

Comment: Ok thanks - I was aware of getting resources within a resource group. It's a shame that there's no API for child resources yet. I might be able to work around it though by correlating with the providers list for the resource type.

Comment: why do you think it is needed when there are docs? upvote if this answer helped

Comment: I'm building a monitoring system for Azure resources and automatic discovery of resource and metrics is a requirement

Comment: And yes, I know monitoring is built into Azure - this is quite a specialized case :)